# How to connect Python SqlModel with AWS RDS in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on an AWS Lambda function that utilizes Python's SqlModel library to interact with an Amazon Web Services Relational Database Service (AWS RDS). However, I'm encountering difficulties establishing the connection between SqlModel and AWS RDS within the Lambda environment.

hese are the steps I've attempted:

Set up an AWS RDS instance (MySQL) with the necessary configurations.
Developed a Python function using SqlModel to connect and perform database operations locally, which works successfully.
Attempted to migrate this function to an AWS Lambda function to execute within the AWS cloud environment.
Despite configuring the required IAM roles, VPC settings, and ensuring the necessary packages are included in the deployment package, I'm facing connection issues between SqlModel and AWS RDS specifically within the Lambda function context.

I would greatly appreciate guidance or insights into any specific configurations, security settings, or code adjustments necessary to successfully connect Python's SqlModel with AWS RDS within the AWS Lambda environment. If anyone has successfully achieved this integration or has experience with similar setups, your advice or code snippets would be incredibly valuable.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Please be more specific about the "connection issues" you are facing. Is there an error message? Is your Lambda function timing out? Is the Lambda function connected to the same VPC as the RDS database? What is the configuration of the Security Groups on the Lambda function and the RDS database? Basically, please provide more information so that we can actually assist you.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)